# Storing exact C file content in database with php

Tags: php, html, database

I am working in a php project. I have to store the content of a C file into database. But it's been a poor experience for me. I used 'long text' data type to store. It seems if the content starts with '#' it doesn't store anything. There are some other problems like not detecting newline character and multiple space character. Can you please suggest a solution? I'm a php beginner.

Comment: `#` indicates the start of a comment in sql, look into using prepared statements to avoid this kind of error

Comment: then how can store exact C file into database @andrew

Comment: You need to show some code, we cant help you without seeing what the problem may be

Comment: Use some SQL abstraction layer like [Zend Db](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-db/) that has built-in means to escape special SQL characters.